# Using PDO with foreach()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to insert some values into my MySQL database using PDO and a foreach loop. When I do it, it only puts in one result.

Here is my code:

```
$config['db'] = array(
'host' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '*NOT NEEDED*',
'dbname' => 'demoScript'
);
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$config['db']['host'].'; dbname='.$config['db']['dbname'], $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);
$url = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/demoScript/uploads';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach($xml->entry as $entry){
    $title = $entry->title;
    $db->query("INSERT INTO videos VALUES('*','".$title."','*','*','*','*','*')");
}
```

*excluded for example

Anyone have any code examples that work. Maybe someone could look at the XML file to see if I'm missing something

**EDIT:** Here is how my DB is set up

[Click for DB Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5XO8.png)

Comment: Looping Works fine over here! Maybe your are running into a unique value issue when inserting. Can you show your database schema?

Comment: @tlenss Just click the link under the edit part to view how my DB is set up

Comment: You shouldn't be inserting '*' values into int fields that's for sure.

Comment: @tlenss I'm inserting real data, but just excluded it for the purpose of this question. I made the video_id the unique index. Do I need to change my query now?

Comment: It's not clear what you are inserting there... Try @Akam's suggestion

Answer (score 1):

change your code like this, so that you can echo the query and also, adding bulk record in one query is better than adding single record per query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO videos VALUES ";
foreach($xml->entry as $entry){
    $title = $entry->title;
    $values[] ="('*','".$title."','*','*','*','*','*')";
}
$query = $query.implode(",", $values);
//echo $query 
$db->query($query);
```

Comment: After looking over the code for way too long, (sorry about that) I don't think it's a code error. I executed the code, then checked the DB. No results. I copied the query that was echoed on the page, pasted it into the DB manually and it worked. It must have encountered an error while being 'sent' to the database.